# Concatenate multiple std::vectors taking duplicates into account in c++17

Tags: c++, vector, concatenation

Even though it is straight-forward to concatenate two `std::vectors` in C++, especially with ranges, I have a slightly different problem.

Say I have the following vectors: `{1,2,6}`, `{6, 8, 9}`, `{9, 8, 10}`, and so on. If the tail of one vector is the same as the head of the next vector that is being concatenated to, I want only one element to be in the final vector, something like this:

`conc({1,2,6}, {6,8,9}, {9,8,10}, {0, 1}) = {1,2,6,8,9,8,10,0,1}`

I was able to do this using `if` conditions, but I do not think it is efficient as I have to do this hundreds of thousands of times, preferably using STL and no external libraries.

In case it might help, there will always be only 4 vectors that have to be concatenated.

Edit: There might or might not be the same elements at the end and beginning of the vectors that are being concatenated.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1{1,2,6};
    std::vector<int> v2{6,8,9};
    std::vector<int> v3{9,8,10};
    std::vector<int> v4{0, 1};

    std::vector<int>V{v1};
     
    

    if (v1.back() == v2.front())
    {
        for(auto it= v2.begin()+1; it != v2.end(); ++it)
        {
            V.push_back(*it);
        }
    }
    else
    {
         for(auto it= v2.begin(); it != v2.end(); ++it)
        {
            V.push_back(*it);
        }
    }

    //repeat the above prcess for other vectors
    
}
```

Comment: please show your code. You forgot to ask a question. You are looking for a standard algorithm?

Comment: @Morpheus How are these vectors {9,8,10}, {0, 1} concatenated?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow just put them next to each other {9,8,10,0,1}

Comment: Do you only _think_ it's ineffecient or did you actually _meassure_ that this part of your code is slowing down you program so much that it might be worth to improve it? Often one worries way to much about performance.

Comment: I am on my way home. I will post the code soon.

Comment: I'm confused - `f({9,8,10}, {0, 1})` doesn't meet your criterion of tail n == head n+1.

Comment: I mean the duplicates might or might not be there. I will update this and let you know.

Comment: There's no standard algorithm for this. You can probably write one yourself, no?

Comment: @idclev463035818 I added my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v1 = {1,2,6}, v2 = {6,8,9}, v3 = {9,8,10}, v4 = {0, 1};
    
    for ( auto p : { &v2, &v3, &v4 } )
    {
        auto it = std::begin( *p );

        if ( v1.back() == p->front() )
        {
            std::advance( it, 1 );
        }           

        v1.insert( std::end( v1 ), it, std::end( *p ) );
    }
    
    for ( const auto &item : v1 )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 6 8 9 8 10 0 1
```

Or you can preliminary reserve enough space in the vector v1. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v1 = {1,2,6}, v2 = {6,8,9}, v3 = {9,8,10}, v4 = {0, 1};
    
    std::vector<int>::size_type n = v1.size();
    auto last = v1.back();
    
    for ( auto p : { &v2, &v3, &v4 } )
    {
        n += last == p->front() ? p->size() - 1 : p->size();
        last = p->back();
    }
    
    v1.reserve( n );
    
    for ( auto p : { &v2, &v3, &v4 } )
    {
        auto it = std::begin( *p );

        if ( v1.back() == p->front() )
        {
            std::advance( it, 1 );
        }           

        v1.insert( std::end( v1 ), it, std::end( *p ) );
    }
    
    for ( const auto &item : v1 )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I did add my code but yours looks miles more elegant than mine.

Comment: I should have added the info that I do not want to destroy v1, v2, v3 or v4. But I can take it from here. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Morpheus Just declare a new vector and in the range-based for loop include the element &v1.

Comment: For `n += `, I'd probably just `std::accumulate` the sizes, and if it's too high by ~2, who cares?

Comment: And given that we're talking algorithms, maybe `std::cout << item << ' ';` should be `std::copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout));`

Comment: Why is `p` a pointer? Why not `for (const auto& v : { &v2, &v3, &v4 } )`?

Comment: @MooingDuck In your statement v is a pointer. More precisely a reference to pointer.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow. slightly unrelated but is there an established style that specifies spacing in the () and {}? I mean you write ( v1 ) instead of (v1). Is it your personal style or is there a name for it. It is very interesting

Comment: @Morpheus It is my personal style. I am sure it makes programs more readable.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow My mistake, I meant `for (const auto& v : { v2, v3, v4 } )`. Then you could use `v.begin()` and such directly, which seems more readable to me

Comment: @MooingDuck In this case you are creating copies of the vectors.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow sorry for bothering you again. Have you configured your editor to automatically format your code in this style or do you manually do it? Also which editor do you use?

Comment: @Morpheus  It is my habit to format code such a way that does not depend on an editor.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use an auxiliary container such as a `std::deque`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> concat(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& v2d)
{
    std::deque<int> sDeque;
    for (auto& v : v2d)
    {
        for (auto v2 : v)
        {
            if (sDeque.empty())
                sDeque.push_front(v2);
            else
            if ( sDeque.front() != v2 )
                sDeque.push_front(v2);
        }
    }
    return { sDeque.rbegin(), sDeque.rend() };
}

int main()
{
    auto v = concat({ {1,2,6}, {6,8,9}, {9,8,10}, {0, 1} });
    for (auto i : v)
        std::cout << i << " ";
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 6 8 9 8 10 0 1
```